# neo4j store the number of edges which a node has as an atribute on the relationship (a way of making the graph weighted)

Tags: neo4j

[this is how the situation looks like, in this example, I want to have a weight of 4 on each edge, then I can delete the duplicates and like this I can have the graph weighted for my situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8L5E.png)I want to count the number of duplicate edges from each node in my graph and then to put that number on one edge to make the graph weighted.

Is there a query which will help me achieve this?

Comment: Do you have only one relationship type or many ?

Comment: I work now with one relation, but I have to add one more relation after I finish the graph with one, the next relation will be mapped_to. I want to ask you if the query will work differently if there are more relationships?

Comment: My query takes in count all the outgoing relationship (whatever their type is). Take a look at the pattern : `(n)-[r]->(m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WITH n, m, count(r) AS count
  CREATE (n)-[:AGGREGATED { weight:count}]->(m)
```

But this query is not performant at all because you're working on the entire graph, and you will probably put all your database in RAM.

So you have to batch this query  :

```
MATCH (n) WHERE size((n)-[:AGGREGATED]->()) = 0 AND size((n)-->()) > 0 
WITH n LIMIT 1000
  MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
  WITH n, m, count(r) AS count
    CREATE (n)-[:AGGREGATED { weight:count}]->(m)
    RETURN count(*)
```

You can execute this query again and again till its result is not 0.
And if you are lazy, there is a procedure in APOC to do that :

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
    MATCH (n) WHERE size((n)-[:AGGREGATED]->()) = 0 AND size((n)-->()) > 0 
    WITH n LIMIT $limit
      MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
      WITH n, m, count(r) AS count
        CREATE (n)-[:AGGREGATED { weight:count}]->(m)
        RETURN count(*)", {limit: 1000});
```

Comment: I tried the queries (except the last one), and they work only if I create another type of relation, I would like to add the count as a property on the existent relation (HAS_CHILD). thank you for the help and interest

Answer (score 0):

by modifing this query 
MATCH (n) WHERE size((n)-[:AGGREGATED]->()) = 0 AND size((n)-->()) > 0 
WITH n LIMIT 1000
  MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
  WITH n, m, count(r) AS count
    CREATE (n)-[:AGGREGATED { weight:count}]->(m)
    RETURN count(*);

I arrived at the point where I want with the following query

OPTIONAL MATCH (u:Disease)-[r:HAS_CHILD]->(o:Disease) WITH u,o,count(r)as count CREATE (u)-[r:HAS_CHILD{weight:count}]->(o) RETURN u,r,o;

[THE RESULT AFTER DELETING DUPLICATES RELATIONSHIPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y3Fd.png)

Comment: Is there a way to modify the query to work for a large amount of data?